# Validar si existe un dato en un arrayList al intentar introducir un dato en Java

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase y estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de intentar hacer una validación para que cuando yo introduzca un dato por consola valide si está o no dentro de ese ArrayList.Lo he intentado hacer con un .contains(producto)==codigo(seguramente esté mal compuesto).Os dejo primero el enunciado:

***cargarArticulo***: Incluye la petición de datos del objeto a cargar en la colección, valida los datos recibidos, la creación del objeto de tipo Articulo, comprueba que no hay ningún producto ya en la colección con el mismo código y añade el objeto creado a la colección.

Codigo cargarArticulo:

(el arraylist se llama coleccion)
private ArrayList coleccion = new ArrayList();

```
public String cargarArticulo(){
    String codigo=null;
    String descripcion=null;
    String existencias=null;
    String cadena = "Código del producto: " + codigo + "Descripción del producto: " + descripcion + "Total de existencias: " + existencias;
    boolean errorProducto = false;
    try{
        //Pedimos que se introduzca el código del producto
    do{
        System.out.println("Introduzca el código del artículo: ");
        codigo = teclado.nextLine();
        errorProducto = ValidarCodigo(codigo);
        System.out.println("Introduzca la descripción del producto: ");
        descripcion = teclado.nextLine();
        errorProducto = ValidarDescripcion(descripcion);
        System.out.println("Introduzca las existencias del producto: ");
        existencias = teclado.nextLine();
        errorProducto = ValidarExistencias(existencias);
        Articulo producto = new Articulo();
        producto.setCodigo(codigo);
        producto.setDescripcion(descripcion);
        producto.setExistencias(existencias);
        if(coleccion.contains(codigo)==codigo){
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Código añadido");
        coleccion.add(producto);
    }while(errorProducto);


    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return cadena;
    }
```

Comment: Te sobra el `==codigo` en la condición

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para verificar si un dato se encuentra dentro de un ArrayList se utiliza:

```
nombreColeccion.contains(valor)
```

Lo anterior devuelve como resultado true si el valor se encuentra dentro de la colección y false en caso contrario. Por lo tanto, tu condición debería ser:

```
if(coleccion.contains(codigo)){
     //Aquí la búsqueda devolvió true puesto que, lo encontró dentro de la colección 
     System.out.println("El código ya existe");
}else{
     //Devolvió false, no lo encontró. Entonces se registra
     System.out.println("Código añadido");
     coleccion.add(producto);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tio!